# Recreate a command as an event with arguments

Tags: wpf, xaml, events, binding, material-design-in-xaml

I am trying to rewrite the command below as an event, I am doing this following the guidelines in Arnaud Weils Learn WPF MVVM book.

```
<ToggleButton Margin="8 0 16 0" Command="{Binding ToggleBaseCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsChecked}" />
```

The event version would look something like

```
<Button Content="Send commands to device" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedDarkButton}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
         <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
             <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}"
                                  MethodName="ToggleBaseEvent"/>
         </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

The ToggleBaseCommand looks like this in the viewmodel:

```
public ICommand ToggleBaseCommand { get; } = new AnotherCommandImplementation(o => ApplyBase((bool)o));

private static void ApplyBase(bool isDark)
{
    new PaletteHelper().SetLightDark(isDark);
}
```

When creating the ToggleBaseEvent the issue that I am experiencing is how to pass the relative source to this method. With the command version, this seems relatively simple but there is no apparent CommandParameter equivalent to the event version. I am wondering if you know how I can get around this or am I better off implementing the ICommand way of doing things.

Comment: The `CallMethodAction` has no means to provide an argument to the method. You could use an `InvokeCommandAction` instead, but that's ugly - a button already provides a convenient way to invoke a command. By the way, why do you want to switch to events? Is there any particular issue you're trying to solve?

Comment: A command is not an event and raising an event is a different thing than invoking a command. What exactly are you trying to do and why?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I would like to recreate the light dark theme toggle used in the [materialdesigninxaml library](http://materialdesigninxaml.net/)
As for why events over commands in the book he specifies that events that run methods are often easier to read, can be bound to events other than "click" and i dont have to implement Icommand.

Comment: So my suggestion to you: for the buttons, use the `ICommand` way. I don't think that the 7-lines event solution you posted is 'easier to read' than the 1-line command binding solution. The `ICommand` pattern is well-known and easy to implement.